# Получение размеров картинки из <input type="file"/>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не удаётся получить размеры загружаемой картинки:

```js
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e) {
    if (typeof FileReader == "undefined")
        return true;
    var elem = $(this);
    var files = e.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
        if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    previewDiv = $('#logo-preview', elem.parent());
                    var image = e.target.result;
                    alert(this.width);
                    bgWidth = previewDiv.width() * 2;
                    previewDiv.css({
                        "background-size":"100%",
                        "background-image":"url("+image+")",
                        "background-repeat":"no-repeat",
                    });
                };
            })(file);
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="upload">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <label>Select a File:</label>
        <div id="logo-preview"></div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А к чему фокусы с замыканием `file`, если вы это значение во внутренней функции не используете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получить размеры картинки можно, использовав `new Image()` для `theFile.target.result` (загруженного с помощью `FileReader`'a файла):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=file]').change(function(e) {
        var elem = $(this);
        var files = e.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(theFile) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.onload = function() {
                    console.log(this.width);
                };
                image.src = theFile.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="upload">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <label>Select a File:</label>
        <div id="logo-preview"></div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Просто `FileReader` нельзя использовать потому, что он работает с любыми файлами, а "ширина" для, например, текстового файла бессмысленна. Поэтому поля `width` в нём нет.