# Как загрузить файл на сервер через xhr, JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, файлы, post, xhr

Пользователь нажимает на ссылку и появляется окно выбора файла

Но до загрузки файла на сервер скрипт должен знать размер файла, размер изображения в пикселях и вывести изображение в HTML-тэг img

Файл загружается посредством POST-запроса

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Хорошая "задача". Коротко... Там нужно... преобразовать файл в base64 данные, потом запихнуть в img, и подождать пока его стейт не станет "загружен", а потом можно посмотреть его размеры. За тем, этот base64 можно отправить. А стоп... вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449802/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-input-type-file

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение размеров картинки из <input type="file"/>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449802/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-input-type-file)